# compare fields after removing spaces in two files with Regex tools

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I am new to awk and need to find  the statement to compare two fields in files below
The columns are , seperated

```
1.csv
_________
1space, aspace

2,b

space3space,c

2.csv
____________
1space,spacea   

space2,bspace
3,spacecspace
```

---

The below statement works fine if there are no leading or training spaces in the fields of either of 1.tsv or 2.tsv

```
nawk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++;next} !(a[$1,$2])'  2.tsv 1.tsv
```

Kindly let me know how can we modify the above statement to trim leadind and lagging spaces and then compare. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is not working? What is the output you are getting and whats your desired output?

Comment: I need space to be removed from 1.tsv and 2.tsv and then compare so that $1 of both files are matched perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
{ key=$1; gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",key) }
NR==FNR { a[key]; next }
!(key in a)
' 2.tsv 1.tsv
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Like the way you made `gsub` common for both files. Minor correction, `gsub` syntax is missing `)` and I believe OP wanted `!(key in a)`, but I guess that is trivial for him to figure out. :)

Comment: fixed, thanks for the corrections. Also, notice thatby saving $1 in a variable ad then modifying THAT, it preserves the file as-is for output and avoids recompiling the records using OFS so no need to set that or worry about the consequences (more of a problem with other FS settings).

Comment: If I want to compare more than one fields, is there a better way than:
nawk -F, '{ key1=$1; gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",key1) ;key2=$2; gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",key2) }NR==FNR { a[key1,key2]; next }!((key1,key2) in a)' 2.tsv 1.tsv

Comment: @Awknewbie: Arguably `awk -F, '{key=$1 FS $2; gsub(/(^|,) *| *($|,)/,"",key)} NR==FNR { a[key]; next }!(key in a)' 2.tsv 1.tsv`. You can use `FS` instead of an explicit `,` in the RE by surrounding it in double quotes instead of slashes and jumping out of the quotes around the FS: `awk -F, '{key=$1 FS $2; gsub("(^|"FS") *| *($|"FS")","",key)} NR==FNR { a[key]; next }!(key in a)' 2.tsv 1.tsv` so it's more robust if the FS changes but it becomes a bit harder to read and you may need to escape some of the characters (test it if you care).

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
NR==FNR {
    gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$1)
    a[$1]++
    next
}
{
    gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$1); 
    if (!($1 in a)) {
        print
    }
}' 2.tsv 1.tsv
```

Comment: 1 ,a
2,b
 3 ,c
is the result I am getting. Column 1 in both files matches if we ignore leading and trailing space

Comment: Whats your expected result then? I don't get any output which shows that your file matches.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's#\s*(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*#/\\s*\1\\s*,\\s*\2\\s*/p#' file1|sed -f - file2
```

```
$cat file1
1 , a
2,b
 3 ,c

$cat file2
1 ,a
 2,b
3,c
$sed -r 's#\s*(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*#/\\s*\1\\s*,\\s*\2\\s*/d#' file1|sed -nf - file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim all the spaces from `$1` before trying to locate it in array `a`:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{$1=$1;a[$1]++;next} {f1=$1; gsub(/ /, "", f1); 
           if (!a[f1]) print}'  2.tsv 1.tsv
```

Comment: I am getting result as 1space,a and 2,b